# Submitting PHP variable for range to d3.scaleOrdinal

Tags: php, d3.js

Is it possible to pass a PHP variable

```
(f. i. $strColors = "(['#1f77b4', '#aec7e8', '#8c564b', '#aec7e8', '#c49c94', '#aec7e8', '#c49c94', '#aec7e8', '#ff7f0e'])
```

to the `range` of a `d3.scaleOrdinal()`?